# Multithreading with nested functions with dependant variables

Tags: python, multithreading

My code (I don't know if I need to show the entire code or not for this problem, sorry if I don't):

```
class GridWithWeights(SquareGrid):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.weights = {}

    def cost(self, from_node, to_node):
        x = from_node[0]
        y = from_node[1]

        results = {(x-1, y+1):14, (x, y+1):10, (x+1, y+1):14,
                   (x-1, y):10,                (x+1,y):10,
                   (x-1, y-1):14, (x, y-1):10, (x+1, y-1):14
                   }
        try:
            return results[to_node]
        except Exception:
            return 0    
        def in_bounds(self, id):
    (x, y) = id
    return 0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height

    def passable(self, id):
        return id not in self.walls

    def neighbors(self, id):
        (x, y) = id
        results = [(x-1, y+1), (x, y+1), (x+1, y+1),
                   (x-1, y),                (x+1,y),
                   (x-1, y-1), (x, y-1), (x+1, y-1)
                   ]
        if (x + y) % 2 == 0: results.reverse() # aesthetics
        results = filter(self.in_bounds, results)
        results = filter(self.passable, results)
        return results

def reconstruct_path(came_from, start, goal):
    current = goal
    path = []
    while current != start:
        path.append(current)
        current = came_from[current]
    path.append(start) # optional
    path.reverse() # optional
    return path

def heuristic(a, b):
    (x1, y1) = a
    (x2, y2) = b
    return abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2)

def a_star_search(graph, start, goal):

    frontier = PriorityQueue()
    frontier.put(start, 0)
    came_from = {}
    cost_so_far = {}
    came_from[start] = None
    cost_so_far[start] = 0



    while not frontier.empty():
        current = frontier.get()

        if current == goal:
            break

        # The thing I want to multiprocess

        for next in graph.neighbors(current)
            new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + graph.cost(current, next)
            if next not in cost_so_far or new_cost < cost_so_far[next]:
                cost_so_far[next] = new_cost
                priority = new_cost + heuristic(goal, next)
                frontier.put(next, priority)
                came_from[next] = current

    return came_from, cost_so_far

diagram4 = GridWithWeights(360, 240)
diagram4.walls = [(2,5),(1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 7), (3, 8)]  # Obstructions
start, goal = (141, 42), (54, 190)
came_from, _ = a_star_search(diagram4, start, goal)
print(reconstruct_path(came_from, start=start, goal=goal))
```

However, I am trying to multithread the for loop highlighted and so I use ThreadPoolExecutor and run it as such:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def func(next):
    new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + graph.cost(current, next)
    if next not in cost_so_far or new_cost < cost_so_far[next]:
        cost_so_far[next] = new_cost
        priority = new_cost + heuristic(goal, next)
        frontier.put(next, priority)
        came_from[next] = current

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()

while not frontier.empty():
    current = frontier.get()

    if current == goal:
        break

    pool.map(func, graph.neighbors(current))


return came_from, cost_so_far
```

The problem is that the dependant variable 'came_from' only contains the last process's data...

The expected result:

```
 Big dictionary of values like the result I get except start to 
 finish(run it yourself). The only reason I didn't put it here is 
 because it keeps freezing my computer
```

Results I got:

```
{(141, 42): None, (140, 43): (141, 42), (141, 43): (141, 42), (142, 43): (141, 42), (140, 42): (141, 42), (142, 42): (141, 42), (140, 41): (141, 42), (141, 41): (141, 42), (142, 41): (141, 42), (139, 41): (140, 42), (139, 42): (140, 42), (139, 43): (140, 42)}
```

Now I cannot access other items I would need. I am using multithreading to speed up the process of generating the dictionary. I am baffled as to what I need to do now and what I am doing wrong. The reason I am generating all these values is for coordinates on a grid and for a path on a grid.

Comment: Just as an FYI, there are very few cases when you should ever show your actual code. You should show the entirety of a minimal example that can be used to reproduce the specific issue you are having. Constructing this basic example is a part of the debugging process. If the minimal example somehow doesn't have the same problem, despite performing the actions that you think trigger it, it us up to *you* to determine why.

Comment: Yup, I would like a minimal example reproducing the issue.